# Using indexing from two arrays to form a matrice

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix, syntax-error

I have two arrays as such:

array_a and array_b

I would like to form a matrice/array com_total such that com_total(i,j) is assigned when array_a(i) and array_b(j) is used.

I have begun with initialising com_total as a zero matrice with number of rows is the number of elements in array_a and the number of columns is the number of elements in array_b.

I then tried to assign the index of each array to my matrice:

```
com_total = (com_total(i,j) for i in array_a for j in array_b)
```

However, upon further testing, the error below keeps popping up:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

How would I fix this? My outcome would just be com_total(i,j) when array_a(i) and array_b(j) are used.